# defalut valued field cannot be null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table that contains boolean fields with default value.

```php
$table->boolean('status')->default(false);
```

but it gives this error when my input is null : "Column 'status' cannot be null".

I thought that if the input is null, db set status false as default. Should I use nullable? but this time 'status' field will be null not false.

validation:

```php
'form.status' => 'nullable',
```

Comment: make it nullable `$table->boolean('status')->nullable();`

Comment: then use $table->boolean('status')->default(false)->nullable();

Answer (score 2):

try `php artisan migrate:fresh` and insert into the form again

if it doesn't work use `$table->boolean('status')->default(false)->nullable()`